# MKStoreKit Implementation

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have spent the last 2 days fighting trying to get in app purchases working! The app has not been approved by Apple (its not ready yet), so I just did the Developer Pulled Binary method. I added a non-consumable (and I am pretty sure my contracts are cleared) and called it com.MYAPP.MYAPPNAME.levelone

I am using the MKStoreKit 3.1 relevant

I just want to see that the item will appear in the NSLog for the app, so I have this in my App Delagate

```
   - (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{

    [MKStoreManager sharedManager];
    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] purchasableObjectsDescription];
        ...
```

When I run this it just tells me

```
Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: com.mycompany.myapp.005
Problem in iTunes connect configuration for product: com.mycompany.myapp.featureA
```

This is a Cocos2d based game if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 4):

There are reasons why I didn't implement MKStoreManager to accept a set of products as parameters.
1) You should not litter your code with hard coded product ids. This is because you initiate a purchase request with a product id. The former happens on AppDelegate and the latter happens on one of your view controllers. So there should be *some* file where you put in all those product constants. Why not use MKStoreManager.h itself for that?

Comment: +1: Kumar, you've done an outstanding job with MKStoreKit v4. Just wanted to say thanks...

Answer (score 3):

MKStoreKit 3.1 requires some configuration before you use it; it doesn't just work out of the box.

Specifically, you need to tell MKStoreKit the list of features/product identifiers that you have configured in iTunes Connect. Oddly, you do that by modifying the source code, instead of passing in an array of arguments.

Examine [MKStoreManager.h lines 26-34](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/blob/master/MKStoreManager.h#L28):

```
// CONFIGURATION STARTS -- Change this in your app
define kConsumableBaseFeatureId @"com.mycompany.myapp."
#define kFeatureAId @"com.mycompany.myapp.featureA"
#define kConsumableFeatureBId @"com.mycompany.myapp.005"
// consumable features should have only number as the last part of the product name
// MKStoreKit automatically keeps track of the count of your consumable product

#define SERVER_PRODUCT_MODEL 0
// CONFIGURATION ENDS -- Change this in your app
```

You have to change that stuff. If you don't, you'll get errors like the one you posted.

But that's not the only place. You also have to update the `requestProductData` implementation function in [MKStoreManager.m](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/blob/master/MKStoreManager.m#L135), where `kFeatureAId` and `kConsumableFeatureBId` are used.

```
-(void) requestProductData
{
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects: 
                                  kFeatureAId,
                                  kConsumableFeatureBId,
                                  nil]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}
```

You have to specify the product identifier list yourself; MKStoreKit can't guess it for you.

Still, it's weird. It makes you wish MKStoreKit would just accept an array of product identifiers in its initializer!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the unused products inside MKStoreManager.m as follows

```
-(void) requestProductData
{
    SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObjects: 
                                  kFeatureAId,
                                  //kConsumableFeatureBId,
                                  nil]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request start];
}
```